# More then half of my project has been deleted in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

More then half of my project just deleted.
I am working with visual studio and i had backup which disappeared somehow.
I saved my project even too many times and I opened it after i restarted my computer and nothing deleted, but when I opened it today my code wasn't there.
Code got deleted from every part of my project when I wrote my project from its start to the end in that order.
Can someone please help me to find a solution?
By the way, I have to send the project in 4 days.

Comment: Look on the disk? Start using git mercurial svn or even cvs

Comment: start coding again... and remember to use gitlab this time. or you can try easeus paid version(buy or tpb) for one last luck

Comment: Are the files still on the filesystem? If so, it sounds like the csproj file excluded some code files from your project. From Solution Explorer click "Show All Files" and if you notice your code files in grey right click them and select "Include In Project".

Comment: Every time I reach some sort of internal 'milestone' on my projects, (eg. compiles without error, links, starts without immediate AV etc), I make a backup subfolder on another drive and copy everything in.  That on top of 'normal' version control and system backups.  You can't have too many backups.

Comment: Thats the weird part guys, the code just disappeared and so do my backup, its like someone sabotaged it.

Comment: In this case, you should urgently contact your local police station instead of stack overflow... I use VS2008/VS2013 since 2009. I never lost files which I didn't delete by myself. (Though, I deleted accidentally files _by myself_ from time to time.) Even if used wrong (e.g. clean project while source folders and build folders are identical) it's hard to believe that VS should have done this.

Comment: If it was just a joke you may find your files/folders in the RECYCLER. If it was more serious (i.e. files really deleted) than you could try to undelete files with an "undelete tool" (no experience about this). If it was evil (i.e. files have been wiped out) then I would fall back to the "police station" option... (In the latter case, start re-coding immediately.)

Comment: I am only 16 years old Scheff, its like a school project, so.... calling to the local police wont help. Thanks anyway, I guess that I will have to write the code from the beggining again.